# numpy 2 arrays added together resulting in same array but shifted

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

[image]

So I have data, in the form of 2 numpy arrays, that look like the above when plotted. For some reason, when I add the 2 numpy arrays together, element-wise as such:

c = a + b

and then plot c, I get this:

[image]

All I'm doing is plot.plot(c)

But that doesn't make sense right? I shouldn't get the same exact plot as plot b (except shifted up) when adding those 2 together right? I'm really confused about this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. However, plot can be deceiving. `a` is almost constant: max changes is about `2e-3` compare to `0.7` in `b`.

Comment: I see. Is there any way I can make it so that the changes in a are more strongly reflected when added together?

Answer (score 0):

`a` is practically a constant, the variations in `a` are much smaller than the variations in `b` so when you sum them together you only wind up seeing the variations in `b` on a plot. This will be more apparent if you plot `c = 1000*a + b`

Comment: I see, hm.. do you mean doing 1000*a + b will make the changes more apparent?

Comment: @dooder yes; the variation in `a` is so small that it may as well just be `a=5.95` when it gets added to `b`, which has large variations. So multiplying `a` by 1000 will increase the size of its variations enough to be noticeable, for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the other answers above.  I think it will be much clearer to the original poster if they try drawing all three plots on the same graph, rather than showing each of them on a separate graph.

```
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
plt.plot(a + b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I see. Is there any way I can make it so that the changes in a are more strongly reflected when added together?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?  Have you tried what @Michael suggested?

Comment: Oh ok, I just tried it. Yes, that looks much better. Would it better to instead normalize values a and then add them together though? Thank you!

Comment: You still haven't told us what you're trying to achieve.  So we can't recommend to you how to achieve it?  We have no idea what a or b are supposed to represent, nor what their sum is supposed to be.